# How to filter based on conditions within a range?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Group   Gene    Score   direct_count    secondary_count   Avg_Score    Upper_SD_Threshold
  1    AQP11    0.31          4                5             0.3            0.48
  1    CLNS1A   0.27          0                2             0.3            0.48
  1    RSF1     0.49          3                6             0.3            0.48
  2    CFDP1    0.58          1                2             0.57           0.60
  2    CHST6    0.59          1                3             0.57           0.60
  2    UBL      0.56          1                3             0.57           0.60
  2    TMEM     0.61          0                0             0.57           0.60
  3    ACE      0.634         1                1             0.63           0.63
  3    NOS2     0.6345        1                1             0.63           0.63
  4    Gene1    0.1           10              20             0.5            0.55
  4    Gene2    0.68          3                1             0.5            0.7
  4    Gene3    0.7           0                1             0.5            0.7
  5    AGT      0.75          0                0             0.00           0.00
```

I am trying to select genes per group based on some filters:

1. Keep/select the gene if it is the only gene in its `Group` (Group 5 in my example)
2. Keep the top scored gene if its `Score` is higher than the `Upper_Threshold` in its `Group`. If more than 1 gene is higher then take filter them in steps 4 and 5.
3. If all genes are less than the `Upper_SD_Threshold` but are also within the range of the `Avg_Score` and the `Upper_SD_Threshold` select them to move into filtering step 4.
4. Select the gene with the largest `direct_count`, if both genes have the same `direct_count` move to step 5.
5. Select the gene with the largest `secondary_count`, if both genes also have the same `secondary_count` then keep both genes.

Ultimately there should always be at least 1 gene selected for all groups, and I am stuck on coding step 2 and setting up the range.

Currently I am trying:

```
new_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(if(n() > 1) {(Score < Upper_SD_Threshold) } else TRUE) %>%
  filter(between(Score, Avg_Score, Upper_SD_Threshold)) %>%
  slice_max(direct_count, n = 1) %>% 
  slice_max(secondary_count, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This is not doing as I expect it to at all and I suspect it's to do with how I am setting up the range between `Avg_Score` and `Upper_SD_Threshold` but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Input data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Gene = c("AQP11", "CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", 
"CHST6", "UBL", "TMEM", "ACE", "NOS2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", 
"AGT"), Score = c(0.31, 0.27, 0.49, 0.58, 0.59, 0.56, 0.61, 0.634, 
0.6345, 0.1, 0.68, 0.7, 0.75), direct_count = c(4L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 0L), secondary_count = c(5L, 
2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Avg_Score = c(0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.57, 0.63, 0.63, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0), Upper_SD_Threshold = c(0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.63, 0.63, 0.55, 0.7, 0.7, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Expected output:

```
Group   Gene    Score   direct_count    secondary_count   Avg_Score    Upper_SD_Threshold
  1    RSF1     0.49          3                6             0.3            0.48 #Only gene > upper
  2    TMEM     0.61          0                0             0.57           0.60 #Only gene > upper
  3    ACE      0.634         1                1             0.63           0.63 #ACE and NOS2 match both counts
  3    NOS2     0.6345        1                1             0.63           0.63
  4    Gene2    0.68          3                1             0.5            0.7  #highest direct_count
  5    AGT      0.75          0                0             0.00           0.00 #only gene in group
```

Comment: what's this `XGB3label`?

Comment: also, what happens if every score is under `Avg_score` and the group is more than 1? Kinda weird to ask, because it is impossible that all numbers are under their average..but apparently that's not the average within the group

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, XGB3label is just the ```Score```, I've renamed the columns so it's clearer. If everything is under ```Avg_score``` then I would filter them under the ```count``` columns too and keep whichever has the highest count. I made up the averages without actually calculating them, for the sake of the example is just about the range between that number and the ```Upper_SD_Threshold``` and you're right none should be under the average so hopefully I can ignore placing this rule in too